# Karate - $ | not a string (LIST:STRING) failure

Tags: karate

Karate DSL:
I have a problem with assertion using regex, which works fine with Karate version 0.9.6, but fails with version 1.0.1 (1.0.0 as well).

This is the failure message coming from Karate:

```
And match response.data[*].rule.url contains "#regex .*https://example.com/Invalid_checksum.*"
match failed: CONTAINS
  $ | not a string (LIST:STRING)
  ["https://example.com/Identifier_unknown","https://example.com/Invalid_checksum","https://example.com/Legal_form_"]
  '#regex .*https://example.com/Invalid_checksum.*'
```

As I mentioned - it is working with 0.9.6, so I assume that the regex is writen properly. Something must have been changed since Karate 1.0.0 (?)

Can someone confirm that this is Karate bug or/and have any idea of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, logged here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1568

Workaround - wrap the RHS in an array:

```
And match response.data[*].rule.url contains ["#regex .*https://example.com/Invalid_checksum.*"]
```

Please in future [actually test the RC releases](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1359010765219393538) and provide early feedback to avoid these kinds of surprises. There's a [LinkedIn group](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/10448828/) you can join if needed. Thanks.

Comment: I started using Karate quite recently and found this bug just yesterday, but I'm going to test upcoming RC releases for sure :) Thank you for the workaround, btw.