# Match a list contains any substring

Tags: java, karate

`{ list: [ {field1:"New York", field2:"San Francisco"}, {field1:"Miami", field2:"Chicago"} ] }`

`And match list contains any substring 'Francisco'`

Is there any possible solution so that to verify the list contains a field with a partial string validation in karate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specifically for the List implementation.

```
* def condition = function(x){return (x.field2.contains('Francisco'))}
* def filteredResult = karate.filter(list, condition)
* match filteredResult = '#notnull'
```

*condition* function validates that a list has an object and this object has a specific field to be looking at '*field2*'. Then verifying if this field contains the keyword '*Francisco*'. Karate has a filter function that returns filtered Objects. The last step is to verify if the result is not null.

Comment: your question was not clear and note that I solved for ANY field in the json. anyway glad you found a solution :|

Answer (score 2):

Many options. Here below is a couple. JsonPath is your friend. Please refer to the documentation to understand how this works:

```
* def response = { list: [ {field1:"New York", field2:"San Francisco"}, {field1:"Miami", field2:"Chicago"} ] }
* def values = $response.list[*].*
* match values contains "#? _.includes('Francisco')"
* match values contains "#regex .*Francisco.*"
```

Note that the above is tested for Karate 1.0.1 and the last line may not work as-is because of this open-issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182925/143475